# Linker error when trying to link log4cxx into an Xcode ObjC/C++ program

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker-errors, objective-c++, log4cxx

I have been trying to link log4cxx into my ObjC/ObjC++/C++ project. It compiles but always fails at the link stage due to undefined symbols. By turning on the Xcode build option "Display Mangled Names" I was able to see why this is the case. The mangled names that the linker is looking for are different from the mangled names in the log4cxx.dylib file.

For example

```
"log4cxx::Logger::forcedLog(log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Level> const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, log4cxx::spi::LocationInfo const&) const"
```

becomes

```
"__ZNK7log4cxx6Logger9forcedLogERKNS_7helpers10ObjectPtrTINS_5LevelEEERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS7_11char_traitsIcEENS7_9allocatorIcEEEERKNS_3spi12LocationInfoE"
```

from the linker's point of view. However the closest symbol that nm reports in log4cxx.dylib is

```
__ZNK7log4cxx6Logger9forcedLogERKNS_7helpers10ObjectPtrTINS_5LevelEEERKSbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEERKNS_3spi12LocationInfoE
```

I created this library was created using the Xcode project provided by Apache.

I see that a similar question ([How can I resolve single symbol link error when dynamically linking XCode project to lib4cxx library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865826/how-can-i-resolve-single-symbol-link-error-when-dynamically-linking-xcode-projec)) was asked earlier but there was no useful response.

A resolution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mismatched C++ standard library settings. Some of the code is using the new libc++, and some is using GNU's libstdc++. Choose the one you want and change the project settings so they're consistent.

You can use the c++filt command line tool to un-mangle C++ symbol names:

```
% c++filt __ZNK7log4cxx6Logger9forcedLogERKNS_7helpers10ObjectPtrTINS_5LevelEEERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS7_11char_traitsIcEENS7_9allocatorIcEEEERKNS_3spi12LocationInfoE
log4cxx::Logger::forcedLog(log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Level> const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, log4cxx::spi::LocationInfo const&) const
% c++filt __ZNK7log4cxx6Logger9forcedLogERKNS_7helpers10ObjectPtrTINS_5LevelEEERKSbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEERKNS_3spi12LocationInfoE
log4cxx::Logger::forcedLog(log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Level> const&, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&, log4cxx::spi::LocationInfo const&) const
```

Note for example `std::basic_string` (libstdc++) versus `std::__1::basic_string` (libc++).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know of these competing libraries.

Comment: I have the same issue. When i compile my code with g++ version 4.8 I get the same undefined symbol errors, with g++ version 5.4, however, it works. Due to some technical reasons, i cannot use g__ version 5.4, so I am trying to find a solution for 4.8. When I ran ldd on the object file it has libstdc++ in both cases (4.8 and 5.4). What could be the reason, and how can I resolve this issue?